# WebPack repeatedly injects redundant script tags into index.html on load

Tags: javascript, webpack

Learning WebPack and have set it up to create an index.html from a template and inject a `<script>` tag with a bundle file that includes a unique content hash (to bypass browser caching and ensure new content is loaded), like so: `bundle-[contentHash].js`.

I'm using a `json-server` and running `webpack -d -w` as a script from NPM. When I run the scripts and load the page, it continually adds identical `<script>` tags to the index.html file over and over.

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const webpack = require("webpack")
const path = require("path")
var htmlPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
  // context: path.resolve(__dirname),
  entry: "./client/index.jsx",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/public"),
    publicPath: path.join(__dirname, "/public"),
    filename: "bundle-[contentHash].js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new htmlPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html"
    })
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The repeated `<script>` tag injection was caused by having the name of the template (index.html) the same as the name of the default output of `html-webpack-plugin`.

Renaming my template from `index.html` to `template.html` fixed the issue.

```
  plugins: [
    new htmlPlugin({
      template: "./public/template.html"
    })
  ]
```